# Storage of the Halogens in PTFE Bottles

Tags: safety, elements

I'm looking to buy some Iodine for various reactions, and noticed that the person who sells it has it in a glass jar with a plastic lid of unknown type.

I'm looking up chemical resistance charts and it says that Iodine, Chlorine and Bromine both work absolutely fine when placed inside of a PTFE bottle, assuming that the Chlorine is not in a gaseous form. 
As for Fluorine, one website states that it attacks the plastic severely, whereas the other states that the PTFE is resistant until around the 100°C mark.

These sites are both [**here**](https://www.zeusinc.com/materials/ptfe/chemical-resistance-chart-ptfe) and [**here**](http://www.calpaclab.com/teflon-ptfe-compatibility/).

Now when I go look at people asking the question, "How should I store elemental Iodine?", everyone seems to respond along the lines of keeping it in a glass jar with a ground glass joint or PTFE/Teflon lined cap.

However since my research suggests that PTFE alone is capable of storing Iodine, is this a viable option? I would love to know from past experiences, because no-one seems to recommend PTFE on its own on any site I checked. Of course however I will also be storing said PTFE container inside of another non-reactive material container.

I understand that I'm probably better off just storing it in glass containers but I have PTFE bottles lying around and would like to use them if at all possible.

Since this question revolves around the Halogens themselves, could the same be potentially done for Bromine and Chlorine?

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34190/is-there-any-chemical-that-can-destroy-ptfe-or-teflon?s=5|0.9921 http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6183/does-a-sulfuric-acid-nitric-acid-mixture-dissolve-ptfe-ie-teflon?s=9|0.5349 Teflon is very resistant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though PTFE is not *attacked* by the halogens, they may discolor PTFE (particularly iodine, and at elevated temperature), [since the plastic is somewhat permeable to halogens (end even to water).](http://dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/776947.pdf)

Comment: Hmm... I might be better off just buying a glass jar with a Teflon-only lid instead. Thanks for the reference, some good source material for later storage!